# how to use goto in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have written following code

```
setlocal

set /A sample =1 

:first

type C:\test.txt | find "inserted"

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto test

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto exam

:test

echo "testloop" >> C:\testloop.txt

set /A sample = %sample% + 1 

if %sample% LEQ 4 goto first

:exam

echo "exam loop" >> C:\examloop.txt

endlocal
```

but it is going to lable "exam" even though error level is not equal to "1" plz help me

Answer (score 7):

Your problem isn't goto, its that errorlevel requires special treatment, it's not like an ordinary environment variable.  The only test you can do with errorlevel is to test whether it is greater than or equal to value.

so you have to test errorlevel values from highest to lowest because if errorlevel 1
then `if errorlevel 1` will be true, but `if errorlevel 0` will *also* be true

```
setlocal
set /A sample =1 

:first
type C:\test.txt | find "inserted"

if errorlevel 1 goto exam
if errorlevel 0 goto test

:test
echo "testloop" >> C:\testloop.txt
set /A sample = %sample% + 1 

if %sample% LEQ 4 goto first

:exam
echo "exam loop" >> C:\examloop.txt

endlocal
```

if you have command extensions enabled, and there is no environment variable called ERRORLEVEL (case insensitive). Then in theory you can use %ERRORLEVEL% like an ordinary environment variable.  So this should also work

```
setlocal EnableExtensions
set /A sample =1 

:first
type C:\test.txt | find "inserted"

if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto exam
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto test

:test
echo "testloop" >> C:\testloop.txt
set /A sample = %sample% + 1 

if %sample% LEQ 4 goto first

:exam
echo "exam loop" >> C:\examloop.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to list the error levels in descending order (errorlevel2, errorlevel1, errorlevel0...).

See [this explanation and example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/39585).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using `ERRORLEVEL` as direct branching as follows:

```
setlocal

set /A sample =1 

:first

type C:\test.txt | find "inserted"

**goto :Branch%ERRORLEVEL%**

:Branch0

echo "testloop" >> C:\testloop.txt

set /A sample = %sample% + 1 

if %sample% LEQ 4 goto first

:Branch1

echo "exam loop" >> C:\examloop.txt

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `||` instead of `errorlevel` for branching. Here's an example

```
setlocal
set /a sample=1

:first
(Type c:\test.txt | find "inserted" >> c:\testloop.txt) || goto :branch1
set /a sample+=1
If %sample% leq 4 goto :first

:branch1           
Echo "exam loop" >> c:\examloop.txt
```

Comment: Stephan, thanks to formatted properly, don’t why post code inproper format.

Comment: because you didn't format anything. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

More simple way to use for loop.

For /l %%a in (1,1,4) do (

(Type c:\test.txt | find “inserted” >> c:\testloop.txt) || goto :done

)

:done

Echo “exam loop” >> c:\examloop.txt

Goto :eof